# Pesquisa mongo entre dois valores

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Bom preciso fazer uma pesquisa em uma `collection` onde tenho `XI, XF, YI e YF` irei mandar por exemplo `x:10, y:9` assim preciso identificar quais itens de local satisfazem aquela localização.

Dado os itens salvo no banco:

```
[{
  XI: 1,
  XF: 5,
  YI: 5,
  YF: 20
},
{
  XI: 6,
  XF: 11,
  YI: 21,
  YF: 36
},
{
  XI: 16,
  XF: 21,
  YI: 37,
  YF: 52
},
{
  XI: 22,
  XF: 27,
  YI: 53,
  YF: 68
},
{
  XI: 28,
  XF: 33,
  YI: 69,
  YF: 84
},
{
  XI: 34,
  XF: 39,
  YI: 85,
  YF: 100
}]
```

Tentei fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
locais.find({
$and: [
  {
    XI: { $gte: 10 },
  },
  {
    XF: { $lte: 10 },
  },
  {
    YI: { $gte: 12 },
  },
  {
    YF: { $lte: 12 },
  },
]
}).then((teste) => {
  console.log(teste)
});
```

});

Porém assim ele esta indo no banco e pegando os valores do banco que esta ele o numero que falei.

Answer (score 0):

Meu erro estava na logica que eu estava utilizando,

```
XI <= meu_numero >= XF
```

Está seria a logica que deve ser utilizada. E para isso precisei trocar as ordens do `$gte` e `$lte`